Is there any return value of truncate() in Laravel?
I'm currently working on a function in Laravel to check whether the truncate function successfully removes data from a table. In this function, I also echo a success or failure message. While the function is successfully deleting all the data in the table, it's echoing the "failure" message. I'm not sure why this is happening.
public function truncateCheck() {
    $users = DB::table('seconddatas')->truncate();

    if ($users) {
        echo "Data truncated successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to truncate data";
    }
}

web.php
Route::get('/aryancrud/truncateCheck',[AryanController::class,'truncateCheck']);

Data is getting deleted from the file, but I am getting "Failed to truncate data". Why? Can someone help with this?

No, it's return type is void

If truncate fails, it fails with an exception not with an error return value. If you want to just echo success or failure wrap it in a try-catch

i know try catch can be a solution but  if else statement should work but its not working, i dont have any foreign keys at all. function is working fine but printing the failure echo statement. why? @apokryfos

truncate() returns void, so $users will never ever have a value. Don't use an if/else, it will always hit the else. Use the try/catch as apokryfos suggested.

The truncate method does not return a value known as void. void is a falsy value, so your condition will always be false, and the code in the else statement will execute.
Please refer to the source code of the truncate method: Database/Query/Builder::truncate. It does not return any value.

great, nicely explained "Database/Query/Builder::truncate" and you also added a new approach to my research on methods. a big thanks to you!
